# No data populating In VF table. Could anyone please help?

Tags: apex, controller, class, lightning-datatable

The following code is of an api call.

```
public with sharing class customeQuery{    
    
    // Initialization
    public string companyName{get; set;}
    
    public List<consoleWrap> ConsoleWrapperList {get; set;}
    public List<Object> ConsoleWrapperList2 {get; set;}
    public finalWrapper results {get; set;}
    
    public class consoleWrap{
        public string NAME ;    //ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC
        public String BVDID;    //NL34179503
        public String COUNTRY_ISO_CODE; //NL
        public String NACE2_CORE_CODE;  //6420
        public String CONSOLIDATION_CODE;   //C2
        public String YEAR_LAST_ACCOUNTS;//2007-12-31T00:00:00
        public Double OPRE; //356895755310.0586
        public Double EMPL;
    }
    
    public class finalWrapper{
        public List<consoleWrap> Data {get; set;}
    }
    
    public PageReference showRecord(){
        List<consoleWrap> ConsoleWrapperList = new List<consoleWrap>();
        List<Object> ConsoleWrapperList2 = new List<Object>();
        
        // Input from the user
        String str =  companyName ;
        
        //create a rest endpoint
        string requestEndPoint = '************************' ;
            
        // requests        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(requestEndPoint);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('ApiToken', '**********************');   
        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');  
      
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

         if (response.getStatusCode() == 200 && response.getBody() != null){
            finalWrapper results = (finalWrapper)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),finalWrapper.class);
           
            ConsoleWrapperList = results.Data ;
            System.debug('The result is ===>> '+ ( ConsoleWrapperList));               
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The apex code is:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="{! companyName}" >
                 
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! ConsoleWrapperList}" var="index">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{! index.NAME}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Bvdid" value="{! index.BVDID}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            
            </apex:pageBlock>
```

But the data is not populating on the resultant table. I am gettign only the headerValue and not the value. Could anyone please help?

The Debug window shows:

> The result is ===>> (consoleWrap:[BVDID=NL34179503,
> CONSOLIDATION_CODE=C2, COUNTRY_ISO_CODE=NL, EMPL=null,
> NACE2_CORE_CODE=6420, NAME=ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC,
> OPRE=3.568957553100586E11, YEAR_LAST_ACCOUNTS=2007-12-31T00:00:00],
> consoleWrap:[BVDID=GB04366849, CONSOLIDATION_CODE=C1,
> COUNTRY_ISO_CODE=GB, EMPL=83000.0, NACE2_CORE_CODE=0610, NAME=ROYAL
> DUTCH SHELL PLC, OPRE=3.45056E11,
> YEAR_LAST_ACCOUNTS=2019-12-31T00:00:00])

Comment: Can you show what's in ConsoleWrapperList when you debug it?

Comment: @AlbaRivas added the ConsoleWrapperList debug file. Please help I am stuck at this point for a long time now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the declaring the instance variables as properties in your inner class:

```
public class consoleWrap{
    public String NAME {get; set;} //ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC
    public String BVDID {get; set;} //NL34179503
    public String COUNTRY_ISO_CODE {get; set;} //NL
    public String NACE2_CORE_CODE {get; set;} //6420
    public String CONSOLIDATION_CODE {get; set;} //C2
    public String YEAR_LAST_ACCOUNTS {get; set;} //2007-12-31T00:00:00
    public Double OPRE {get; set;} //356895755310.0586
    public Double EMPL {get; set;}
}
```

I tested your use case with the following code and it worked fine:

// VF page

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cws}" var="cw">
                <apex:column value="{!cw.NAME}" />
                <apex:column value="{!cw.BVDID}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

// Apex controller

```
public class TestController {
    
    public List<ConsoleWrap> cws {get; set;}
    
    public class ConsoleWrap{
        public String NAME {get; set;}    //ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC
        public String BVDID {get; set;}    //NL34179503
    }
    
    public TestController() {
        ConsoleWrap cw = new ConsoleWrap();
        cw.NAME = 'ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC';
        cw.BVDID = 'NL34179503';
        cws = new List<ConsoleWrap>{cw};
    }
   
}
```

Comment: I tried this part too. 

not working

Comment: Alba, I am getting the headers on VF page. But records are not populating for respective header.

Comment: That's weird. I did an isolated test, creating your use case, and it worked. Take a look at my code and check which are the differences with yours.

Comment: Thanks Alba, I dont know what changes I made but its working now. I based my code on your TESTCASE.